Gasket “lidded” Pioneer Woman Crockpot
My lid to my pioneer woman crockpot has a rubber gasket for latching down to travel.  Awful burn rubber smell which over takes the smell of whatever Im cooking.  I dont travel.  Can I just remove this and get it to all pull off or will I still be left with rubber residue.  This had to be a big complaint for this particular pot!

I've never seen one of these, can you edit and put some pictures on?

Are you sure the gasket is intended to be left on while cooking?

is this the type of crockpot you're talking about? It doesn't seem it needs to be removed for cooking https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/85bf28d9-a303-44b4-b791-ffdec303e4fa_1.51c5520697dfdf86a296251b889647b4.jpeg

The gasket is necessary when cooking.  Have you tried taking it out and thoroughly cleaning it?
